# Is there syntactically better way of reverting to the constructor state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that I would like to revert to the constructor values when fired again. While this code works, is there a better way to write this syntactically?

```
    class DoubleClick extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            tagMessage: 'Hello',
            btnMessage: 'Click Me',
            on: true
        }
    }

    clickHandler = () => {
        if (this.state.on) {
            this.setState({
                tagMessage: 'Double Clicked',
                btnMessage: `I'm Clicked!`,
                on: false
            })           
        } else {
            this.setState({
                tagMessage: `Hello`,
                btnMessage: `Click Me`,
                on: true
            })                
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.tagMessage}</h1>
                <button onDoubleClick={this.clickHandler}>{this.state.btnMessage}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An obvious simplification would be to store the common state value in a shared variable:

```
const onState = {
    tagMessage: 'Hello',
    btnMessage: 'Click Me',
    on: true
};
const offState = {
    tagMessage: 'Double Clicked',
    btnMessage: `I'm Clicked!`,
    on: false
};
class DoubleClick extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = onState;
    }

    clickHandler = () => {
        if (this.state.on) {
            this.setState(offState)           
        } else {
            this.setState(onState)                
        }
    }
    …
}
```

However, that there are only two values this object can possibly have hints at a deeper problem: you don't actually need those many state properties. A simple boolean state would be enough, the message details can go in the `render` method:

```
class DoubleClick extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = true;
    }

    clickHandler = () => {
        this.setState(!this.state);
    }

    render() {
        const tagMessage = this.state ? 'Hello' : 'Double Clicked';
        const btnMessage = this.state ? 'Click Me' : `I'm Clicked!`;
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{tagMessage}</h1>
                <button onDoubleClick={this.clickHandler}>{btnMessage}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: For future reference, from a performance stand point, is this way better than creating the properties in the constructor ? Or, is it negligible in this case as there are only 2 properties?

Comment: @buzz Absolutely negligible, given it's just a constant overhead, but yes in theory react needs to do less work when comparing old state to new state if there are less properties. The advantage of simplicity is mostly a benefit for the reader and maintainer of the code.

Answer (score 1):

What about creating **const** with **defaultState**?

```js
const defaultState = {
    tagMessage: 'Hello',
    btnMessage: 'Click Me',
    on: true
}

class DoubleClick extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = defaultState 
    }

    clickHandler = () => {
        if (this.state.on) {
            this.setState({
                tagMessage: 'Double Clicked',
                btnMessage: `I'm Clicked!`,
                on: false
            })           
        } else {
            this.setState(defaultState)                
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>{this.state.tagMessage}</h1>
                <button onDoubleClick={this.clickHandler}>{this.state.btnMessage}</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create initial state variable and then when required, set the state to that initial value

e.g.

```js
const initialState = {
    tagMessage: 'Hello',
    btnMessage: 'Click Me',
    on: true
};
class DoubleClick extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = { ...initialState };
    }
    // Call this when required
    setToInitialState = () => {
      this.setState({ ...initialState });
    }
}
```